# PHP PDO (PostgreSQL): can't get multiple parameters to work

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, prepared-statement

I have the following, and I can't get it to work:

```
$pdo = new \PDO('pgsql:host=xxxx;port=xxx;dbname=xxx;user=xxx;password=xxx');

$foo = 123;
$bar = 123;

$query = '
SELECT *, 
(
    SELECT allow
    FROM foo 
    WHERE foo_field = ?
    AND lorem.lorem_id = foo.lorem_id
) as foo_allowed, (
    SELECT allow
    FROM bar
    WHERE bar_id = ?
    AND lorem.lorem_id = bar.lorem_id
) as bar_allowed
FROM lorem';

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $foo);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $bar);
$stmt->execute();

var_dump($stmt->fetchAll());
```

The code above gives me the following error:

> **Message**: An exception occurred while executing '(query)': SQLSTATE[08P01]: <>: 7 ERROR: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but
>   prepared statement "" requires 1

I tried the same in mysql and it worked fine. I also tried named parameters, but that doesn't work either.

Using PHP version 5.4.6 and PostgreSQL 9.1.7.

@Kovge
I have users, roles and resources. Users can have Resources and Roles can have Resources. A user has one role. In table user_resource there's a field that says if a user is allowed to access the resource. The same for roles.
I want a table (HTML table) with all the resources and see if a user is allowed to access a resource or not (first via user_resource, then role_resource)

Comment: May be you need joins? Or `foo_allowed` and `bar_allowed` will have the same values over the rows.

Comment: @Jari Maybe a join is a good idea indeed, but for the foo_allowed and bar_allowed, I get those values from to different tables so how can they become the same values over the rows?

Comment: Also, I tried the same query in mysql and it worked just fine..

Comment: What is the result you want to see? Could you add to your question a sample output what you expect from the query?

Comment: @Kovge and Jari thanks for the suggestions you made. I tried a simpler query and that worked..I think i will go for the join query

Comment: PHP and PG versions? I suspect you're hitting a bug in the PHP PostgreSQL driver statement parser, myself.

Comment: Have you tried executing the query with hard coded values to see if there is anything that is tripping up postgres, ie. syntax error etc?

Comment: Did you try replacing the single quotes delimiting the query string by double quotes? I'm sure double quotes can be used for multi line strings but I don't know about single quotes.

Comment: I changed the query and used Join instead now..maybe when I have time left (boss is sitting next to me :p) I will try to add the double quotes. @craigringer PHP version is 5.4.6 and PG I don't know..it's an external database. Navicat says Server version 90107, but I'm not sure if thats PG's version

Comment: @AlbertBakker To get the Pg version run `SELECT version()` as explained in the info page for [tag:postgresql] and the PostgreSQL documentation.

Comment: @CraigRinger PostgreSQL 9.1.7

Answer (score 1):

Could you use table joins instead? So your query becomes something like:

```
SELECT l.*,
       f.allow,
       b.allow
  FROM foo_allowed f INNER JOIN
       lorem l ON ( l.lorem_id = f.lorem_id ) INNER JOIN       
       bar_allowed b ON ( l.lorem_id = b.lorem_id )       
 WHERE f.foo_field = ?
   AND b.bar_field = ?
```

I haven't tested this so the syntax may be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried calling the execute directly without the bind.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute(array( 1 => $foo, 2 => $bar));
```